# "Ghostscript conversion error" when use GeneratePageThumb method in GhostScript to generate thumbnail from PDF file

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I am facing an issue when I try to generate thumbnail from a special PDF file (GeneratePageThumbs works well with other PDF file). I am getting an exception when I call GeneratePageThumbs method of Ghostscript(x86)  as following:

> at GhostscriptSharp.GhostscriptWrapper.CallAPI(String[] args)    at
>   GhostscriptSharp.GhostscriptWrapper.GeneratePageThumbs(String
>   inputPath, String outputPath, Int32 firstPage, Int32 lastPage, Int32
>   width, Int32 height)    at
>   GhostscriptSharp.GhostscriptWrapper.GeneratePageThumb(String
>   inputPath, String outputPath, Int32 page, Int32 width, Int32 height)

Special PDF file here:
  http://www.filedropper.com/201573

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Ghostscript Sharp here. While that uses Ghostscript you need to be careful about the way you use the terms. You can't use a GenerateThumb method in Ghostscript because there is no such entity in Ghostscript.

My guess is that the filename is the problem, try renaming the file to something which uses the ASCII character encoding rather than Chinese glyphs.

If that works, then you need a newer version of Ghostscript. Or possibly of Ghostscript Sharp, but I can't help you with that.

Comment: Thank for your help.
I was used old version of Ghostscript.